# How to avoid a user with edit access in google sheet from accessing to the script properties?

Tags: security, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Imagine this scenario: I have created a Google sheet and shared it with a user with edit access. He opens the sheet, fills a cell with a product ID, and presses a button. I have assigned an app script to the button that calls an HTTP API to fetch the product specs using its ID. I have stored the x-api-key in the script properties. The problem is that the user can easily read the script properties and see the x-api-key. What is the best practice to avoid him accessing the script properties? Any other ideas are welcome.

Comment: New Attack vector found: Custom functions can get userproperties of the owner. The method in my answer is not secure.

Comment: This is a duplicate. I will add the link later. Create an add-on.

Answer (score 1):

New Attack vector found: [Custom functions can get userproperties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions?hl=en#using_services) of the Spreadsheet owner. This method is not secure, unless both users are editors.

---

- Store it in `UserProperties`
- Create a version of your script(by deploying a dummy web app or library - doesn't need to work)
- Use a installable edit trigger to run as "me"(you), which accesses userprops to get data.
-  Make sure the edit trigger is at a specific version created by you. This way, the end user can't alter the code.

Related: [Allow script to edit locked cells](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64355436/)

Answer (score -1):

You can create a script, write the api_key in the property and add a function to return this key. Deploy this script as a library.

```
function get_key(){
  return PropertiesService.getScriptProperties("api_key")
}
```

The trick is that when copying a script or container, the properties are not copied. But no one will prevent the user from using the console and looking at the key, so it is better to transfer all the logic to the library

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).