Google App Scripts work 100% for me, but no one else
I have written a simple spreadsheet to record archive entries for an historical society. First tab is a data entry form where the user inputs each record’s detail. The other tabs simply display all previously entered records in different views. A final tab is used as a working tab for temporary data.
A few scripts are used for selecting archive record topics, saving (adding) the (form) entries to a spreadsheet row, searching for an individual record, abandoning an entry, etc. The whole spreadsheet works 100% - for me! As we need to add some 1,000 archive records to the database, we aim to share the workload across all members. However, whenever anyone else attempts to enter an archive record they get a general ‘error’ (without any detail at all).
All users have accepted the script authorisation / permission to run. Editing access has been given to all with a link, those cells in the form entry tab not used are protected (so as to avoid corruption of non-used cells).
The runtime errors occur when any of the form buttons to Save, Delete, Exit are selected. Errors differ but usually say ‘an error has occurred’ or ‘one is trying to edit a protected cell’. No detailed information of the error is given - see images of errors.
Example 1: 
Example 2:

Attached to each form button is a script thus triggered when the button is selected.
Script code for ‘Save/Update’ button:
// Function to get values from all form fields and post to the Master Archive List
// for a new entry. It will update the entry if this is a change process
function getandPostFormData()  
{                              
// Set initial settings for variables
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const avcWS = ss.getSheetByName('Add/View/Change');
const listWS = ss.getSheetByName('Master Archive List');
const settingsWS = ss.getSheetByName('Settings');
var CurrentRow = settingsWS.getRange("L4").getValue();  // == current row of exiating record (if one has been found)

// Check that all fields are correctly entered ...
// first all topic entries are set to non-blank.

var checkitcell = avcWS.getRange('C7'); // Check if the Topic has been selected
var checkit = checkitcell.getValue();
var checkitlength = checkit.length;

if(checkitlength == 0)
{
alertMessage('Sorry, you need to select a Main Topic for this archive item.',1);
return;
}

var checkitcell = avcWS.getRange('C8'); // Check if the Sub Topic 1 has been selected
var checkit = checkitcell.getValue();
var checkitlength = checkit.length;

if(checkitlength == 0)
{
alertMessage('Sorry, you need to select a Sub-topic 1 for this archive item.',1);
return;
}

var checkitcell = avcWS.getRange('C9'); // Check if the sub-topic 2 has been selected
var checkit = checkitcell.getValue();
var checkitlength = checkit.length;

if(checkitlength == 0)
{
alertMessage('Sorry, you need to select the last Sub-topic 2 as well.',1);
return;
}

// Check if the title has been entered
var checkitcell = avcWS.getRange('C12'); // Check if title is blank
var checkit = checkitcell.getValue();
var checkitlength = checkit.length;

if(checkitlength == 0)
{
alertMessage('Sorry, please give a Title to this archived item.',1);
return;
}

// Now check if the actual location is blank
var checkitcell = avcWS.getRange('E15'); // Check if locaton is blank
var checkit = checkitcell.getValue();
var checkitlength = checkit.length;

if(checkitlength == 0)
{
alertMessage('Sorry, the Actual Location of the archived item needs to be given.',1);
return;
}

// Check if any entry has changed for existing record and update if they have
if(settingsWS.getRange("L3").getValue() === "E")
{
    if(settingsWS.getRange("L6").getValue() != avcWS.getRange("C5").getValue())        // Status
      {listWS.getRange(CurrentRow,1).setValue(settingsWS.getRange("L6").getValue());}  
    if(settingsWS.getRange("L7").getValue() != avcWS.getRange("C7").getValue())        // Topic
      {listWS.getRange(CurrentRow,2).setValue(settingsWS.getRange("L7").getValue());}
    if(settingsWS.getRange("L8").getValue() != avcWS.getRange("C8").getValue())        // Sub 1
      {listWS.getRange(CurrentRow,3).setValue(settingsWS.getRange("L8").getValue());}
    if(settingsWS.getRange("L9").getValue() != avcWS.getRange("C9").getValue())        // Sub 2
      {listWS.getRange(CurrentRow,4).setValue(settingsWS.getRange("L9").getValue());}
    if(settingsWS.getRange("L10").getValue() != avcWS.getRange("C12").getValue())      // Title
      {listWS.getRange(CurrentRow,5).setValue(settingsWS.getRange("L10").getValue());}
    if(settingsWS.getRange("L11").getValue() != avcWS.getRange("E12").getValue())      // Description
      {listWS.getRange(CurrentRow,6).setValue(settingsWS.getRange("L11").getValue());}  
    if(settingsWS.getRange("L12").getValue() != avcWS.getRange("C14").getValue())      // Record Typr
      {listWS.getRange(CurrentRow,7).setValue(settingsWS.getRange("L12").getValue());}
    if(settingsWS.getRange("L13").getValue() != avcWS.getRange("C15").getValue())      // Location Type
      {listWS.getRange(CurrentRow,8).setValue(settingsWS.getRange("L13").getValue());}
    if(settingsWS.getRange("L14").getValue() != avcWS.getRange("E15").getValue())      // Actual Location
      {listWS.getRange(CurrentRow,9).setValue(settingsWS.getRange("L14").getValue());}

   // Now clear down the stored details just for ensuring there are no problems later
   settingsWS.getRange("L4:L14").clearContent()  // Not the record type though!
}
if(settingsWS.getRange("L3").getValue() === "N")     // New record logic ...
 {
    console.log(settingsWS.getRange("L3").getValue())
    
    // Next ID logic
    const IDCell = avcWS.getRange('C4');
    const nextIDCell = settingsWS.getRange("G3");
    var nextID = IDCell.getValue();
    IDCell.setValue(nextID); // set C4 to the next value

    // Set these cells for writing the record as they are not entered
    avcWS.getRange("C5").setValue("Live"); // set C5 record status to Live

    // Set up the array for writing / updating the entry recod
    const fieldRange = ["C5","C7","C8","C9","C12","E12","C14","C4","C15","E15"];
    const fieldValues = fieldRange.map(f => avcWS.getRange(f).getValue());

    // Now write next record in the Master Archive List tab
    listWS.appendRow(fieldValues);  // Write a new row in the Master Archive List with the new entry details / record
    nextIDCell.setValue(nextID+1);  // Add 1 to the set the next ID for the next cycle
 }

clearFormData();  // Now clear down cells and display the next ID
settingsWS.getRange("L3").setValue("N");  // Assume next entry will be a new record. It will be changed to E
                                           // when existing one searched for.

} // End of getandPostFormData function


function clearFormData()  // Function to clear the details and redisplay ID
{
  // Set initial settings for variables
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const avcWS = ss.getSheetByName('Add/View/Change');
  const settingsWS = ss.getSheetByName('Settings');
  const IDCell = avcWS.getRange('C4');
  const nextIDCell = settingsWS.getRange("G3").getValue();
  const fieldRange = ["C5","C7","C8","C9","C12","E12","C14","C4","C15","E15","E4"];
  fieldRange.forEach(f => avcWS.getRange(f).clearContent());  // Clear all cells

  // Redisplay the next ID
  IDCell.setValue(nextIDCell); // set C4 to the next value ready for next input cycle

}  // End of function to clear the form details for the next entry cycle

Script code for ‘Exit’ button:
// Function when the Exit button is pressed.
function ExitForm()
{
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var avcWS = ss.getSheetByName('Add/View/Change');
var listWS = ss.getSheetByName('Master Archive List');
var settingsWS = ss.getSheetByName('Settings');
var changed = "N";   // Used to denote some field has been changed

// Anything changed?
if(settingsWS.getRange("L6").getValue() != avcWS.getRange("C5").getValue())        // Status
  {changed ="Y";}  
if(settingsWS.getRange("L7").getValue() != avcWS.getRange("C7").getValue())        // Topic
  {changed ="Y";}
if(settingsWS.getRange("L8").getValue() != avcWS.getRange("C8").getValue())        // Sub 1
  {changed ="Y";}
if(settingsWS.getRange("L9").getValue() != avcWS.getRange("C9").getValue())        // Sub 2
  {changed ="Y";}
if(settingsWS.getRange("L10").getValue() != avcWS.getRange("C12").getValue())      // Title
  {changed ="Y";}
if(settingsWS.getRange("L11").getValue() != avcWS.getRange("E12").getValue())      // Description
  {changed ="Y";}  
if(settingsWS.getRange("L12").getValue() != avcWS.getRange("C14").getValue())      // Record Typr
  {changed ="Y";}
if(settingsWS.getRange("L13").getValue() != avcWS.getRange("C15").getValue())      // Location Type
  {changed ="Y";}
if(settingsWS.getRange("L14").getValue() != avcWS.getRange("E15").getValue())      // Actual Location
  {changed ="Y";}

if(settingsWS.getRange("L3").getValue() == "N" && changed == "Y")  // This is a new entry being abandoned.
                                                                    // Note stored fields will be blank
  {
   if(alertMessage('You appear to have started to enter a new entry. Abandon it?',2) == "Y")
     {clearFormData();
   }
  }

if(settingsWS.getRange("L3").getValue() == "E" && changed == "Y")  // This is an existing that has changed being abandoned.
                                                                    // Note stored fields will be original entry
  {
  if(alertMessage('You appear to have abandoned changes to an existing entry. Abandon it?',2) == "Y")
    {clearFormData();}
  }

  if(changed == "N")    // As nothing has changed, simply clear form data and start again for the next cycle
    {
      clearFormData()
    // Now clear down the stored details just for ensuring there are no problems later
      settingsWS.getRange("L4:L14").clearContent()  // Not the record type though!
      settingsWS.getRange("L3").setValue("N");  // Assume next entry will be a new record.
    }

} // end of Exit function

Script code for ‘Delete’ button.
// Function when button Delete / Reinstate has been pressed.
function DeleteReinstate()
{
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var avcWS = ss.getSheetByName('Add/View/Change');
var listWS = ss.getSheetByName('Master Archive List');
var settingsWS = ss.getSheetByName('Settings');

if(settingsWS.getRange("L3").getValue() == "N")  // Cannot delete / reinstate an entry that has not been created!!
{
  alertMessage('You cannot delete or reinstate an entry that has not been fully entered, yet.',1)
  return;
}

if(settingsWS.getRange("L3").getValue() == "E" && settingsWS.getRange("L6").getValue() == 'Live')  // existing & live
{
  if(alertMessage('Are you sure you want to change the Status to deleted?',2) == "Y")
    {
      avcWS.getRange("C5").setValue('Deleted Entry');  // Update form cell
      settingsWS.getRange("L6").setValue('Deleted Entry');  // Then tempory store
      listWS.getRange(settingsWS.getRange("L4").getValue(),1).setValue('Deleted Entry');  // and in record row too
      return;
    }
} else {  // existing & deleted
  if(alertMessage('Are you sure you want to change the Status back to Live?',2) == "Y")
    {
      avcWS.getRange("C5").setValue('Live');  // Update form cell
      settingsWS.getRange("L6").setValue('Live');  // Then tempory store
      listWS.getRange(settingsWS.getRange("L4").getValue(),1).setValue('Live');  // and in record row too
    }


} // end of Deleted / reinstatefunction


The Complete Spreadsheett with a record entry filled in but just before it goes wrong when any user other than me selects the ‘Save/Update’ button.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gtxTIWjoWOuPm2n3LBMwmhN9WviohLRgFwaid62Fo0I/edit?usp=sharing
Has anyone any idea why only I can run the spreadsheet and how I can get this to be used by others? I have tried searching for this problem but cannot find an answer. All help appreciated.

Have you tried removing the protection from certain cells wherein the setValue function applies? For example: avcWS.getRange("C5").setValue('Live'); In this line I noticed that C5 is protected, hence it is expected to encounter an error since you can't write on this cell.

Another cell that I noticed is C4.

Thank you for the answer. But the reason the cells C4 and C5 are protected is that the user must not enter any value into them. They are generated by the spreadsheet. The ID must be unique and generated; and the status is controlled by the 'Delete' button once the user has searched for and displayed an archived record.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64355436/

Thank you for your suggestion. I need to try and understand this workaround but is this really as complicated as it seems? To me it is a simple requirement to stop users from updating/changing a sheet's cell generated value. I can think of several reasons why one would want this.

A cell is protected or it is not. If a user can edit it, they can edit it  manually or with a script running as them. If they can't edit it, they can't edit it via script either. For a script to edit an item, it needs privileges, which the unprivileged user cannot give - thus the need for installable triggers or service accounts - with privileges given by the owner or another user with privileges. PS: when you reply, use @ to notify the user. For eg, @Gyul

@gyul. Thank you but I am not sure I agree with you as there is a middle option as in my requirement - but another discussion. I will now try and see how to implement triggers / service account but currently looks complicated. A career in IT but first time for App Scripts and indeed Java.

Add Another Range on Protected sheets & ranges
The error that you encountered is because cells C4 and C5 are protected. To resolve this issue, kindly follow the steps below.

Steps:
1.) On your Spreadsheet, right-click on Add/View/Change and select Protect Sheet.

2.) Click Set Permissions
3.) From there, Click on BLHS Users and Add another range
4.) Add C4 and C5.
It should look like this:

5.) Click Done

Output:
Before:

After:


References:

Protect a sheet or range

