# ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() doesn't return actual script URL

Tags: google-apps-script, add-on

My Google Calendar addon is published as **deployment id** `AKfycbwFmqDJdIQDqGIMmujFEzwKZlrBKTPJaIitsHGfmqL72Ehm-YShfk3aJXLcJndQJJCU` as can be seen below:

[image: Deployment ID]

But when setting the add-on "Settings" URL with `createSettingsUrlFunction` and calling the following API:

```js
ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()
```

The returned URL is different from the deployment ID URL:
`https://script.google.com/a/xxx.com/macros/s/AKfycbyy4AAzPl3smU-kdts89HQVaZiUFkFek-TyxwBi0FDsMHALscM/exec`

[image: Different settings URL]

What is this script id `AKfycbyy4AAzPl3smU-kdts89HQVaZiUFkFek-TyxwBi0FDsMHALscM`? I don't have any deployment with this ID. With previous deployments, `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()` always returned the same id (script id == deployment id).

Comment: Related [Behavior of ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() seems to have changed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58843993/1595451), [ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() points to dev URL. How can I get it to point to exec production URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60232532/1595451)

Answer (score 1):

The Script ID and the Deployment ID aren't the same.

The Script ID is unique, no matter if the project is deployed or published as add-on or as web application. By the other hand a single project could have as many Deployment ID as the project is deployed.

There are two type of deployments

- Header deployment
- Versioned deployment

AFAIK the header deployment ID might be the same as the script id but on vesioned deployments the deployment ID will not be the same as the Script ID.

One simple solution to `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()` returning the wrong ID on versioned deployments, is actually a workaround:

> hardcode the ID to be used instead of using `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()`.

The solution might be to use [projects.deployments.list](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.deployments/list), if that is not be overkilling for your project as it requires additional authorization scopes.

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/deployments

Related

- [How to use versioned deployments when programmatically creating triggers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54210044/1595451)
- [ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() points to dev URL. How can I get it to point to exec production URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60232532/1595451)
- [How to correctly display the "Current web app URL" in spreadsheet with `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63911943/1595451)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What bothers me is that `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()` points to a non existing URL.

Comment: It looks like the typical URL used for deployed web apps, maybe it is the URL for your application **if** it were to be deployed as a web app.